# Visualforce renderAs Pdf CSS selector issue [:last-child]

Tags: visualforce, css, renderas

I am developing a visualforce renderas pdf in which I create a table but when I try to use the CSS :last-child selector it doesn't work. However the :first-child selector works. Attached is an example of code that has that behavior.

CSS

```
td:first-child{
   background-color: red;
}
td:last-child{
   background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>td 2</td>
      <td>td 2</td>
      <td>td 2</td>
      <td>td 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>td 3</td>
      <td>td 3</td>
      <td>td 3</td>
      <td>td 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>td 4</td>
      <td>td 4</td>
      <td>td 4</td>
      <td>td 4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The table looks like this
[image]

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong and can you help me? thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

`:last-child` was introduced as part of CSS 3.

The library that Salesforce leverages to turns Visualforce pages into .pdf files, Flying Saucer, only supports up to CSS 2.1 (which is when `:first-child` was introduced).

The adjacent sibling selector can be used instead, but only if you have a constant number of columns for each row (i.e. `td + td + td + td` would select the 4th `td` in each of your `tr`s). Your best bet is probably to simply apply a css class to your target elements.